# Behavior of CollapsingToolbarLayout in Separate Fragment

Tags: android, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I need to implement something that behaves similarly to a [CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html). Two big differences that make this widget inappropriate for my purposes:

1. This is not part of the toolbar. It's a layout that is inflated via a fragment that sits directly beneath the toolbar, but cannot be a child of the toolbar.
2. When I scroll the screen, I want the upper frame layout ('header_fragment_container', which is populated with a child fragment), to collapse just like the CollapsingToolbarLayout. As it does, I want it to be replaced with a different layout.

Does anyone know of an appropriate widget or third party library that can handle this collapsibility outside of the app bar / toolbar?

Here is the xml for the fragment as it exists at the moment:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom solution - listen to the scroll changes and make the layout modifications appropriately :

```
scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {

        private static final int THRESHOLD = 150;
        private int scrolledDistance = 0;
        private boolean toolbarVisible = true;

        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View view, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            if (view.getScrollY() == 0) {
                if(!toolbarVisible) {
                    toolbarVisible = true;
                    showToolbar();
                }
            } else {
                if (toolbarVisible && scrolledDistance > THRESHOLD) {
                    toolbarVisible = false;
                    scrolledDistance = 0;
                    hideToolbar();
                } else if (!toolbarVisible && scrolledDistance < -THRESHOLD) {
                    toolbarVisible = true;
                    scrolledDistance = 0;
                    showToolbar();
                }
            }

            if ((toolbarVisible && scrollY - oldScrollY > 0) || (!toolbarVisible && scrollY - oldScrollY < 0)) {
                scrolledDistance += scrollY - oldScrollY;
            }
        }
    });

private void showToolbar() {
    // show the Toolbar and make the necessary layout modifications
    final ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(toolbar, "y", 0);
    animator.setDuration(1000);
    animator.start();
}

private void hideToolbar() {
    // hide the Toolbar and make the necessary layout modifications
    final ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(toolbar, "y", -getActionBarHeight());
    animator.setDuration(1000);
    animator.start();
}
```